# How to change normal character to password char by jquery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a textbox and I want that when the user types inside it then each character will be converted to a password symbol after 1 sec by jQuery.

The same effect that we see on modern smart-phones when we type into password textboxes.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I know how to capture the key press and get the character user typed.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#username").keypress(function(event){   

// Get the keypress value
// ...?

var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

}

});
</script>
```

Comment: The reason this is done on mobile devices is because of the high probability of "fat-fingering", which is not a concern on a full keyboard.  I would recommend not doing this.

Comment: Jeremy, there are legitimate usability reasons for showing a user the password he entered, though. See e.g. [Nielsen's article](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html) as well as [Schneier's opinion about it](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html).

Comment: Fat-fingering has nothing to do with sexual practices. It just means that your (big) finger is bound to hit a (small) key next to the one you aimed for on your smartphone keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with that: http://jsfiddle.net/89CF8/7/
But it works only if you type correctly.
You should save the value in another variable (I use `letters` array in the example), because standard input only allows you to change it's value for asterisks, losing all that user has been typed.

Issue #1. You should add checking for non-symbols. For example, Del key will add bad symbol to `letters` array.

Issue #2. You should add checking for backspace and use `splice` to remove elements.

Issue #3. If user deletes symbol from the middle of the text, it's very hard to synchronize new value with your variable, which stores the initial value.

After all, I think that it isn't good idea, but maybe my code will help you to find better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You dont actually need to handle key press. Use 1sec timeout loop, and replace all characters in textbox with stars. And dont forget to store characters in a varaible.

Something like below would help you, but you have to spend some time to fix bugs.
http://jsfiddle.net/ymutlu/8BXDu/2/

Comment: Updated answer, but it has some bugs.

Comment: last character being visible until i put another character. anyway u r ver close to what i asked here.

Answer (score 0):

custom mask password by javascript

[custom mask password](https://jsfiddle.net/karimqaderi/74qm3oyv/2)

```
    <style>
    .mask {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    input#pass {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script>

var txt = document.getElementById("txtMask");
var hdn = document.getElementById("pass");


hdn.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){

  txt.value = '';
   for(let i=0; i<hdn.value.length;i++)
       {
           txt.value +='@';
      }         

});
</script>
<div class="mask">
<input type="text" id="txtMask" autocomplete="false">
<input type="text" id="pass">
</div>
```