# Custom glyphs inside password input

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to change the system default glyph to a star or whatever else inside an INPUT password field? I know -webkit-text-security exists, but I'd like to use custom images and/or characters. Is this possible or does any good jQuery plugin exists for this purpose?

Comment: You don't want to do this. You're going to have to hack implement your own character hiding input with javascript. You'd have to do something awful like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933244/how-to-change-normal-charater-to-password-char-by-jquery