# how to replace text input typed characters by stars?

Tags: html

is there any way you could replace typed characters from input type="text" by stars like the input type="password", i searched but didnt find anything yet, can it be done with css?

Let me know thanks!

Comment: Where are Java and Php involved?

Comment: ok guys is the first time i post in here, i understand you are very angry on newcommers, but still...

Comment: what is your requirement? You want a input type='text' field to change to `*` of click of some button?

Comment: No, we aren't angry on newcomers. I didn't downvote so I can only guess but I'd assume the reason is the quality of the question (it's very unclear what you're actually trying to achieve). That being said it's basically obligatory to refer you to [ask].

Comment: Keerthana Prabhakaran what i want is that type='text' field to change to * when you type in it, like it does when you type in a type="password", if i could use directly type="password" i wasnt asking about it in here, my english is not perfect excuse my bad language...

Comment: I suspect you're getting downvoted because you haven't attempted to solve this problem, or done much research to resolve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

generally I think it is recommended that you use `type="password"`, is there any reason that this wouldn't work for what you are requesting?

You could set up a javascript function to call `.OnKeyPress()` (or jQuery's `.keyup()`) to take an action after each key press, but this is not advised at all as the implementation would be unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score -1):

There is a fiddle on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933244/how-to-change-normal-charater-to-password-char-by-jquery) that might help, but +1 for App-Devon too for type=password !